# Codeforces -615C, main idea

Tags: string, algorithm

I came across the explanation of task 615c on the editorial page of codeforces #338, div.2. i can't understand the idea: "The idea is that if can make a substring t[i, j] using k coatings, then we can also make a substring t[i + 1, j] using k coatings. So we should use the longest substring each time". How can it be implied from those sentences that we should use longest substrings each time? could you explain it more clearly? Here is the task: http://codeforces.com/contest/615/problem/C

Answer (score 0):

> Ayrat has scissors and glue. Ayrat is going to buy some coatings(basically is a string) s, then cut out from each of them exactly one continuous piece (substring) and glue it to the end of his track coating. Moreover, he may choose to flip this block before glueing it.

`substring t[i + 1, j]` contains exactly 1 character less compared to `substring t[i, j]`. So if you can cut out `substring t[i, j]` from `k` coatings, then you can surely cut out `substring t[i+1, j]`.

Lets say you are provided with coating `abc`, then you can form `abc` + `cba` = `abccba` using `k(=2)` coatings.

That also means you can form `bccba` (even `ccba`) using `2` coatings.

You just need to cut out one *extra* character(*first* char) from any one of `k` coatings.

Instead, reducing more character(s) from the string-formed-by-`k`-coatings should raise the reverse question "*Can we do it in `k-1` or lesser number of coatings supply?*"

> So we should use the longest substring each time

When you take the longest substring each time, the number of coatings decreases, which is the goal of the problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how is it implied that we should get the longest substrings each time?